# Changing timeline from vertical to horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, timeline

I have a vertical timeline that I'm trying to just flip it to make it a horizontal timeline. It displays great vertically, but I really need it to be horizontal.

I wanted to post the complete css and markup so you all can see all that I'm working with, so please excuse any excess code. Below is my markup and CSS

```css
.timeline {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.timeline:before {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  left: 40px;
  margin-left: -1.5px;
}
.timeline > li {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px;
}
.timeline > li:after,
.timeline > li:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.timeline > li:after {
  clear: both;
}
.timeline > li .timeline-panel {
  width: 100%;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 20px 0 100px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}
.timeline > li .timeline-panel:before {
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: auto;
}
.timeline > li .timeline-panel:after {
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 14px;
  left: -14px;
  right: auto;
}
.timeline > li .timeline-image {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #fed136;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 7px solid #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}
.timeline > li .timeline-image h4 {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
  float: right;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 20px 0 100px;
}
.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:before {
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 15px;
  left: -15px;
  right: auto;
}
.timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel:after {
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-right-width: 14px;
  left: -14px;
  right: auto;
}
.timeline > li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.timeline .timeline-heading h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: inherit;
}
.timeline .timeline-heading h4.subheading {
  text-transform: none;
}
.timeline .timeline-body > p,
.timeline .timeline-body > ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .timeline:before {
    left: 50%;
  }
  .timeline > li {
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
  }
  .timeline > li .timeline-panel {
    width: 41%;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 20px 20px 30px;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .timeline > li .timeline-image {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
  }
  .timeline > li .timeline-image h4 {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
  }
  .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 30px 20px 20px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .timeline > li .timeline-panel,
  .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
    padding: 0 20px 20px;
  }
  .timeline > li {
    min-height: 150px;
  }
  .timeline > li .timeline-image {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    margin-left: -75px;
  }
  .timeline > li .timeline-image h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    line-height: 26px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .timeline > li {
    min-height: 170px;
  }
  .timeline > li .timeline-panel {
    padding: 0 20px 20px 100px;
  }
  .timeline > li .timeline-image {
    width: 170px;
    height: 170px;
    margin-left: -85px;
  }
  .timeline > li .timeline-image h4 {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
  .timeline > li.timeline-inverted > .timeline-panel {
    padding: 0 100px 20px 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <h2 class="section-heading">Section 1</h2>
      <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">This is some subtext</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <ul class="timeline">
        <li>
          <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="thumb.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4>2009-2011</h4>
              <h4 class="subheading">Our Humble Beginnings</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
          <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="thumb.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4>March 2011</h4>
              <h4 class="subheading">An Agency is Born</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="thumb.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4>December 2012</h4>
              <h4 class="subheading">Transition to Full Service</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
          <div class="timeline-image">
            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" src="thumb.jpg" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="timeline-panel">
            <div class="timeline-heading">
              <h4>July 2014</h4>
              <h4 class="subheading">Phase Two Expansion</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="timeline-body">
              <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt ut voluptatum eius sapiente, totam reiciendis temporibus qui quibusdam, recusandae sit vero unde, sed, incidunt et ea quo dolore laudantium consectetur!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="timeline-inverted">
          <div class="timeline-image">
            <h4>Be Part <br/>Of Our <br/>Story!</h4>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add some code to make your timeline work with flexbox. You can then reverse it, horizontal, vertical, etc. I'd imagine you'd have some sort of toggle nav. The user clicks one and it adds a class. The class would be tied to flex box properties.